# Specifying a custom path of beans.xml for CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

When I use Spring and want to write a unit test, I can specify a custom context configuration in various ways, for example, by providing a different path of the `context.xml`.

But I don't see the way how to do that for CDI if I want to use a custom dependencies configuration for testing in the same maven module.

The documentation is [very strict](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic013.htm) about this point:

> For EJB modules or JAR files, the beans.xml deployment descriptor, if
> present, must be in the META-INF directory.

If there is already `/META-INF/beans.xml` in the sources, I can not place a different one into the test-resources (it simply will be ignored).

Is any way to configure `Weld/CDI`, may be by using some system variables, to change the path of the `beans.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For EJB modules or JAR files, the beans.xml deployment descriptor, if present, must be in the META-INF directory.

That is true, however that concerns an already created/packaged JAR which you then use as a dependency of your app. But your app can have it's own `beans.xml` too. `beans.xml` is just a means to define one bean archive and certain structures (interceptors, decorators, ...) **within** that archive. That means, for instance, that an interceptor enabled via `beans.xml` inside that JAR library will not be enabled in your application unless you specify it in `beans.xml` of that app too. Hence the link you see between the documentation and the testing you are asking about might not be correct/relevant. Not sure if I got you right there, though.

> Is any way to configure Weld, may be through using some system variables, to change the path of the beans.xml?

No, there isn't. But in EE you mostly test with Arquillian and that allows you (among other things) to define a test deployment. There you can include any custom `beans.xml` you desire. That's also what Weld/CDI TCK tests use most of the time.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't provide answer on my question. I have one maven module with /main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml, and I have /tests in the same module where I want to use different beans.xml (for example, I want to use another mock service for one of the dependencies)

Comment: @Andremoniy Well, I didn't have enough information about project structure to answer precisely. In your case, second part of my answer applies - **there is no** Weld-specific config for custom `beans.xml` file. You'll have to use some kind of testing library which orchestrates deployment and hence allows you to not include the original `beans.xml`

Comment: @Andremoniy BTW you aren't the first person asking thin question. Maybe it would be worthwhile to create a JIRA feature request? https://issues.jboss.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa